# Упорядоченный вывод бинарного дерева на экран

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть класс сортированное множество (хранится в дереве), необходимо вывести на экран через поток. Обычный вывод через Print есть, а вот как в поток запихнуть не знаю с какой стороны взяться(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно как-то так.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TreeNode
{
    friend  class Tree;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, TreeNode& node);
private:
    T *value;
    TreeNode *left;     // указатель на левое поддерево
    TreeNode *right;    // указатель на правое поддерево
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, TreeNode& node)
{
    // порядок обхода слева направо
    if (node.left)
        out << *(node.left);    
    out << *(node.value) << endl;//для value должен быть определен operator<<
    if (node.right)
        out << *(node.right);

    return out;
}

class Tree
{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, Tree& tree);
private:
    TreeNode *root;
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, Tree& tree)
{
    if (tree.root)
        out << *(tree.root);
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Tree tree;
    /*
    что-то делаем с деревом: добавляем/удаляем узлы, балансируем и т.д
    */
    //теперь запихиваем его в поток
    cout << tree;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то тебе нужно рекурсивно вызывать функцию Print, начиная с первого потомка(если они есть) и заканчивая последним, в самой функции Print, а потом печатать. Это если снизу вверх. А если нужно выводить их сверху вниз, то сначала печать, а потом вызывать Print у потомков.

Comment: Я же говорю у меня все это написано, я не могу понять как должен выглядеть потоковый вывод

Comment: Так и не понял, что тогда тебе надо?
Значит не это?

    void Print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<children_count; i++)
            if(children[i]) children[i]->Print();
        cout << data;
    }

Comment: нет, более того у меня все в дереве а не в массивах